# Issue Update to Library on Maven Central

Tags: android, maven, maven-central

So I used this article [The Complete Guide to Creating and Publishing an Android Library](https://android.jlelse.eu/the-complete-guide-to-creating-an-android-library-46628b7fc879) to release my library to Maven Central. And I managed to do so.

For doing that, I created an account on [Sonatype](https://issues.sonatype.org/) and create a new issue, with the groupId as my GitHub account name. After that, I released my library using the uploadArchives gradle method. And on [Nexus Repository Manager](https://oss.sonatype.org/#stagingRepositories) I closed and released my library. Everything went perfect, and my library was available on Maven Central after a few hours.

### Problems

1. **How do I issue an update to the library???**

   To update the library, I made my changes to the library, and again released it from the Nexus Repository Manager. Then I went to Sonatype to add another comment to the issue that I'd created, however this time the Issue was marked as resolved, and I could not make any new comments. When I tried to create a new issue, it was marked as duplicate and closed immediately. And I've waited for over 3 days and the update has still not gone up.
2. **How do I release a second library using the same group ID (GitHub account name)?** 
   Since I'm unable to create a second issue on Sonatype, I'm unable to release a second library. For this library also I ran the same steps, but the library just won't publish on Maven Central.

I could really use some help here.

Comment: You might also want to look into jitpack: https://jitpack.io - makes the whole process really painless - just push to github - nothing else to do - I only publish my libraries there - I always found maven central painful - jitpack makes the process pleasant ..

Comment: Oh, ok.. Thanks, will take a look at that

Comment: @ligi Thank you so much buddy. Jitpack is so easy to handle. You really helped me out here.

Comment: you are very welcome!

Comment: @Rachit, Could you help me to publish my library to the `Maven Central`?
My question link: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77702335/mavencentral-image-previewpublishreleasepublicationtoimagepreviewrepository-fa